# I think I acidentally removed Ubuntu/files by removing libc6

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I seem to have unintentionally deleted almost everything from Ubuntu using

```
apt-get remove libc6 libc6-dev
```

Is there any chance I can get my files back (with Ubuntu) or will I have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: You will have to reinstall, but that doesn't necessarily mean losing your files.

Comment: You can get it up running from this machine but you will need to download all the core DEBs you removed and manually install them. Quicker is likely to be an install  with "something else"  from the live dvd/usb without formatting any of the partitions, just mount them.

Comment: @Rinzwind Install them how since `dpkg` won't work? ;) I suppose one possible way is to download the library files and manually copy them so that at least apt/dpkg will work, but at that point a reinstall is just simpler?

Comment: @fkraiem The only possible way downloading the individual files would make sense is if you don't have (access to) a Live Ubuntu media, but I'm pretty sure you'll find *something* that fails to load from disk (wasn't in RAM, so got deleted from disk during the `apt-get remove` operation) before you succeed

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you are saying. You cannot install any package on the target system, because its `dpkg` doesn't work (due to the missing libraries). Thus as a temporary measure you can (from a Live system, obviously) download the library files and copy them manually into the `/lib` directory of the target system, so that at least its `dpkg` will work and you can properly reinstall the packages.

Comment: @fkraiem Aha.  I didn't catch that you were suggesting booting from Live media to do the library file downloads; I was thinking that with the system still running, it might be almost possible to load a browser or ftp client and download those libraries (but I'm pretty sure neither a browser nor ftp would work without libc6).  Still, if you have Live media available, it'll be much easier and almost certainly faster to install fresh with the no-format option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a device.

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

Suppose it informs that `/` is `/dev/sda1`, continue running:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste these lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano. Continue running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall libc6 libc6-dev ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
exit
sudo reboot
```

Comment: "Suppose it informs that / is /dev/sda1" ... on a live system?

Comment: @muru:  Habitually the first hard disk  is named /dev/sda and the first  CD/DVD-ROM is named /dev/scd0 or /dev/sr0. It is also just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `apt-get remove` removes everything dependent on the specified package(s), and there's no command to "undo" that (hence reinstalling everything that was removed) -- and further, that it's likely `apt` no longer works without libc6 -- I believe the only option open to you is to reinstall Ubuntu.

As noted in comments, it's possible to reinstall without formatting or partitioning; this will preserve settings and stored user data, though you'll still have to reinstall application packages and items that replaced standard system software (for instance, I use synaptic to manage packages instead of the standard Ubuntu package, because I was used to it before I switched to Ubuntu -- in this situation, I'd have to reinstall synaptic after the Ubuntu installation completes).

Comment: ehm. From a live DVD an install with NO FORMAT is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall *and* get your user files back, see [Ubuntu Reinstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation).

However, I would try to backup my files prior to reinstalling using the live installer. Get a backup drive (USB, SATA, …) and do the following:

1. Boot the Ubuntu installer and exit the installation.
2. Mount your primary hard drive and mount a backup drive.
3. Copy all your important files to your backup drive.
4. Unmount and detach your backup drive, reboot may be necessary depending on drive type.
5. Reinstall Ubuntu now.